# Error while get info from html to controller in Java + Thymeleaf

Tags: java, spring, thymeleaf

I did a controller class with this code:

```
@Controller
public class CadastroController {
    @Autowired
    ClienteRepository clienteRepository;

    @GetMapping("/cadastro")
    public String abrir(Cliente cliente) {
        return "cadastro";
    }

    @PostMapping("/cadastrar_cliente")
    public String cadastrar(Cliente cliente) {
        clienteRepository.save(cliente);
        return "index";
    }
}
```

and this HTML:

```
    
    <form action="#" th:action="@{/cadastrar_cliente}" th:object="${cliente}" method="post">        
    <label class="lbl" for="nome">Nome</label> <br> <br>
    <input th:field="*{nome}" id="nome" type=”text” placeholder="Digite seu Nome Completo:">

    <label  class="lbl" for="email">E-Mail</label> <br> <br>
    <input th:field="*{email}" id="email" type=”email” placeholder="Digite seu E-Mail:">

    <label  class="lbl" for="telefone">Telefone</label> <br> <br>
    <input th:field="*{telefone}" id="telefone" type=”tel” placeholder="Digite seu Telefone">

    <label  class="lbl" for="senha">Senha</label> <br> <br>
    <input th:field="*{senha}" id="senha" type=”password” placeholder="Digite sua senha">

    <input type="submit" value="Cadastrar"><br> <br><br> <br><br> <br>
    </form>
```

But when I debug the controller, the Entity Cliente properties comes null...

I tried the same code in another computer and aparentily works

Anyone know what can be the problem?

I tried debug and convert to modelAndView, View, and others tries. But nothing worked

Answer (score 0):

The problema is in Input type...

Try this, for example:

”password”

To:

"password"